# How to map another object of arrays after a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data that looks like

```
[{subCategory: "subCategory", 
  name: "name",
  data: [{
  GradeName: "grade", 
  Population: "population",
  }]
}]
```

and I am running this code in my component

```
{currentCoinData.map((coin) => (
          <tr key={coin.id}>
            <td>{coin.subCategory}</td>
            <td>{coin.fullName || coin.coinName}</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        ))}
```

How can I map the data key from the array of objects onto the td jsx component?

Comment: is `data` array always of the same size (otherwise you'll get not quite aligned table rows with different number of `<td>` elements in them)?

Comment: Also it looks like you didn't obfuscate your sample code carefully enough, since property names in your JSX code do not match your input object's properties.

Answer (score 2):

just use another map function inside you map function:

```
{currentCoinData.map((coin) => (
          <tr key={coin.id}>
            <td>{coin.subCategory}</td>
            <td>{coin.fullName || coin.coinName}</td>
            {coin.data.map(item =>
                <td key={item.GradeName}>
                    {item.GradeName} {item.Population}
                </td>
            )}
          </tr>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` inside a `.map` just fine:

```js
{currentCoinData.map((coin) => (
          <tr key={coin.id}>
            <td>{coin.subCategory}</td>
            <td>{coin.fullName || coin.coinName}</td>
            <td>{coin.data.map(item =>
                    <span key={item.GradeName}>{item.GradeName}</span>)}
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
```